# How to create a website mockup from PNG files, I just want to add links

Tags: jquery, png, mockups, fireworks

I have a couple of PNG Files from Fireworks and simply want to do a MockUp where I can set Links on the Images in order to load the next image. I have something in mind I think it was a JS or jQuery script but I dont remember it.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day I used to use [image maps](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_map.asp)

If you are not a coder make seperate html pages for each image

```
<a href="/path to next image">
<img src="/path to current image"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS to position clickable divs using absolute coordinates.